# How do you limit what text is used to match a regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have written the following regular express:

```
(^(?=.*?\bran\b)(?=.*?\bfast\b)[^,]*)
```

My objective if for it to match the target string when the text up to the first comma includes both ran and fast.

Target Strings:

1. Jim ran fast, but did win the race => Should match
2. Jim ran well, but John ran fast
   too. => Should NOT match
3. Jim ran well, John ran fast, and Jane ran fast. => Should NOT match

Here is a [working sample at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/buEY25/1)

I'm using the pcre (php)

The problem I'm having is that a currently written the regular express is looking at the whole text string to see if the two words (ran and fast) are present. I want to limit the text to the text up to the first comma, but don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to replace the `.` instances with `[^,]` because `.*?` will include commas, and therefore match any "ran" or "fast" that comes *after* the comma. Here:

```
(^(?=[^,]*?\bran\b)(?=[^,]*?\bfast\b)[^,]*)
```

[**Regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/knes8n/1).

Be aware that `[^,]` will also match new line, so if that's not what you want, you might consider using something like `[^,\n]` or `[^,\r\n]`.

Also, note that your regex will match even if there are no commas. If you want to make sure your match is followed by a comma, you might need to add another positive Lookahead at the end (i.e., `(?=,)`).